# Android BLE 4.0 implementation Between Android Devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, light, energy

Im a beginner at Android Development and i got to develop this app in which i have to connect my Android device will scan and connect with only those devices who are using this app too. And show their names as a list on my scanning device.
Till now i have somehow written the scanning code watching some tutorials but wasn't able to write the broadcasting code.

Plus i want some things to be broadcasted from the broadcasting device like Its name with which its logged in on this App and the AppID to see if it is using the same app or not. Can that be done and how?

Here is the Scanning code.

```
    final Context context = v.getContext();
    final View vi = v;
    BluetoothManager btManager =    (BluetoothManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);

    BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = btManager.getAdapter();
    if (btAdapter != null && !btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);   
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent,1);
    }
    BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[]     scanRecord) {
            devicefound = device;
            UUID = device.getAddress().toString();
            devices = new ArrayAdapter<String>( context , R.layout.device_name);
            ListView pairedListView = (ListView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            pairedListView.setAdapter(devices);
            devices.add(devicefound.getName());

        }
    };
    madapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);
    final BluetoothGattCallback btleGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic     characteristic, int status) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final int status, final int     newState) { 
            // this will get called when a device connects or disconnects
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final int status) { 
            // this will get called after the client initiates a                BluetoothGatt.discoverServices() call
        }
    };
```

Any sort of help will be appriciated. Thanks in advance.